# Is it possible to restart linux server using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, sh

I have an AWS instance running. I need to restart the instance every Monday. Since I need to do it weekly, I need to automate this process by writing a script to run on the server. What is the best way to do this or Can someone give me any resources which will help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a Lambda to program a script execution that will restart the (presumably EC2) server using AWS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a cron job to restart instance at 05:00 every Monday :

```
0 5 * * 1 aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(curl -s http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

You need to run first on the instance :

```
aws configure
```

Answer (score 0):

On the instance itself, you can simply run:

```
sudo restart now
```

Just add that to a `cron` schedule. It's much easier than calling out to the EC2 service to restart the instance.